# May I upload the preprint version of my article to ResearchGate before publication?

Tags: publications, copyright, publishers

Recently, I got an acceptance of a journal paper, where I am allowed to self-archive its preprint version in my own repository/website.

My question is whether I am allowed to upload it to RG before publication, assuming that my RG page is a personal web page. If 'yes', what should I mention in the publication date entry, knowing that it is compulsory?

Comment: Don't mention the date. Is it compulsory?

Comment: I must enter the date in the RG form. On the other hand, should I understand that I am allowed to upload it?

Comment: I supposed that acceptance does not mean a publication date and preprint should be the version submitted to the Journal which might not have a confirmed date of it's publication.

Comment: RG is not a personal website or institution repositories. It seems that there are many discussion here related to this issue (I saw earlier). Why don't you just upload abstract and link to the IEEE DOI?

Comment: _Why don't you just upload abstract and link to the IEEE DOI?_ — Because that wouldn't make the paper freely available.

Answer (score 1):

First you should note that ResearchGate is unlikely to be considered *self archiving* by the publisher. While they may allow it, you should confirm. You should also ask about embargo periods. Assuming the publisher has told you the publication date is compulsory when self archiving, it is not unreasonable to ask what you should do at this stage.

In the absence of guidance, you could use something like *forth coming* or *in press* in place of the date.